# Tomcat and CATALINA_HOME

Tags: java, tomcat, environment-variables

I am messing with Tomcat server and I think some strange thing happened. I downloaded Tomcat 7 from apache website (not an RPM but tar.gz). As I understand there should be CATALINA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE environment variables set, but when I do export on my terminal I can't see any of them, but server starts fine through bin/startup.sh and it even says

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/andrzej/apache-tomcat-7.0.25
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/andrzej/apache-tomcat-7.0.25
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/andrzej/apache-tomcat-7.0.25/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/andrzej/apache-tomcat-7.0.25/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/andrzej /apache-tomcat-7.0.25/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
```

I think that the other day variables were set, but now I tried to use them with keytool to generate certificate and I noticed they are not there. 
Am I missing something, because even if I can't see them everything works fine (startup/shutdown and eclipse with tomcat)?

Answer (score 4):

Those environment variables are optional. If there are none set on the system, Tomcat will just set some defaults based on the location of the currently running script (the `startup.sh` and so on), which will be used as long as Tomcat is running. If you know Shell script language, just open `catalina.sh` file in an editor and read it.

Answer (score 4):

If you take a look into `catalina.sh` (which is called from `startup.sh`) you will notice that in case CATALINA_HOME is not set it automatically sets it to one level above of the program executable:

```
[ -z "$CATALINA_HOME" ] && CATALINA_HOME=`cd "$PRGDIR/.." ; pwd`
```

and CATALINA_BASE, if absent, is set equal to CATALINA_HOME:

```
if [ -z "$CATALINA_BASE" ] ; then
  CATALINA_BASE="$CATALINA_HOME"
fi
```

So there's no real requirement for the variables to be set.