# Where can I find Tomact7 lib folder on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: java, tomcat7

Please give me the specific path to Tomcat7 lib folder?
I tried /usr/share/tomcat7/lib

Comment: Tomcat can be installed in any of several places, it's up to you and/or the package maintainer of the package you used. You'll just have to [`find`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find) it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in the below path:

```
$CATALINA_HOME/lib
```

find out where CATALINA_HOME points to:

```
echo $CATALINA_HOME
```

or, to find where $CATALINA_HOME would be set, please refer:

[Tomcat and CATALINA_HOME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175668/tomcat-and-catalina-home)